# Angular + Angular Material Table With Pagination Server Side

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Pretty new in Angular World ...
I have an Angular project: (Angular: 16.2.6) with Angular Material.
I need to setup pagination in Material Table like this:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {IAgama} from './IAgama';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AgamaService {
  private url = 'http://localhost:8080/v1/agama';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }

  getAll(page?: number, perPage?: number): Observable<HttpResponse<IAgama[]>> {
    let url = (page && perPage)
      ? `${this.url}?page=${page}&per-page=${perPage}`
      : this.url;
    return this.httpClient.get<IAgama[]>(url, {observe: 'response'});
  }

  getByID(id: number): Observable<IAgama> {
    return this.httpClient.get<IAgama>(`${this.url}/${id}`);
  }

  create(agama: IAgama): Observable<IAgama> {
    return this.httpClient.post<IAgama>(this.url, agama);
  }

  update(agama: IAgama): Observable<IAgama> {
    return this.httpClient.put<IAgama>(`${this.url}/${agama.id}`, agama);
  }

  delete(agama: IAgama): Observable<IAgama> {
    return this.httpClient.delete<IAgama>(`${this.url}/${agama.id}`);
  }

}
```

index.component.ts

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChild,} from '@angular/core';
import {IAgama} from '../IAgama';
import {AgamaService} from '../agama.service';
import {MatPaginator, PageEvent} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatSort} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {FlashService} from '../../../../shared/flash/flash.service';
import {Subject, takeUntil} from 'rxjs';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {ConfirmDialogComponent} from '../confirm-dialog/confirm-dialog.component';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-index',
  templateUrl: './index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index.component.scss'],
})
export class IndexComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

  // Handle datatable
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['no', 'id', 'nama', 'alias', 'action'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<IAgama> = new MatTableDataSource<IAgama>();

  // Sort
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;

  // Pagination
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;

  constructor(
    private agamaService: AgamaService,
    private flashService: FlashService,
    private dialog: MatDialog,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    let queryParamMap = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap;
    if (queryParamMap.get('page')) {
      this.paginator.pageIndex = Number(queryParamMap.get('page'));
    }

    if (queryParamMap.get('pageSize')) {
      this.paginator.pageSize = Number(queryParamMap.get('per-page'));
    }

    this.fetchFromAPI();
    
  }

  fetchFromAPI() {

    this.agamaService
      .getAll(this.paginator.pageIndex, this.paginator.pageSize)
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.dataSource.data = response.body || []; // Set rows in table
        if (Number(response.headers.get('X-Pagination-Current-Page')) < 2) {
          this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;  // Set paginator on page = n ?
        }
        this.paginator.pageSize = Number(response.headers.get('X-Pagination-Per-Page'));  // Set Items per page
        this.paginator.length = Number(response.headers.get('X-Pagination-Total-Count')); // Set count all data
      });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  pageChanged(event: PageEvent) {
    this.paginator.pageIndex = event.pageIndex + 1;
    this.paginator.pageSize = event.pageSize;
    this.paginator.length = event.length;

    const queryParams = {page: this.paginator.pageIndex, 'per-page': this.paginator.pageSize};
    this.router.navigate(['/hrd/agama'], {queryParams});

    this.fetchFromAPI();
  }
}
```

index.component.html

```
<!-- List all record based on pagination -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-title">
    <h1>Agama</h1>
    <div>Portal > HRD > Agama</div>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="isFlashMessageVisible">
    <p>{{flashMessage}}</p>
  </div>

  <p>
    <a mat-raised-button color="primary" routerLink="create">
      <mat-icon fontIcon="add_circle"></mat-icon>
      <span>Create</span>
    </a>
  </p>

  <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="no">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No.</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item; let i = index">
          {{ (paginator.pageIndex) * (paginator.pageSize) + (i + 1) }}
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.id }}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="nama">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.nama }}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="alias">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Alias</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.alias }}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Action</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <a
            mat-icon-button
            color="primary"
            aria-label="View"
            routerLink="{{element.id}}"
          >
            <mat-icon>visibility</mat-icon>
          </a>
          <a
            mat-icon-button
            color="primary"
            aria-label="Update"
            routerLink="update/{{element.id}}"
          >
            <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
          </a>
          <button
            mat-icon-button
            color="warn"
            aria-label="Delete"
            (click)="openConfirmDialog(element)"
          >
            <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
    </table>

    <mat-divider></mat-divider>

    <mat-paginator
      #paginator
      [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 100]"
      [length]="paginator.length"
      [pageIndex]="paginator.pageIndex"
      [pageSize]="paginator.pageSize"
      (page)="pageChanged($event)"
      aria-label="Select agama from elements"
      showFirstLastButtons
    >
  
    </mat-paginator>


  </div>

</div>
```

I have two errors that raised in browser:

1. ERROR TypeError: this.paginator is undefined
2. ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: '10'. Expression location: IndexComponent component. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0100

Any guide, suggestion, its so appreciated ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1, It is because you are using `this.paginator` in `ngOnInit`. `@ViewChild` values will be defined when called `ngAfterViewInit`, it is later than `ngOnInit`.

You should transfer them to `ngAfterViewInit`.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }

  fetchFromAPI() {

    this.agamaService
      .getAll(this.paginator.pageIndex, this.paginator.pageSize)
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.dataSource.data = response.body || []; // Set rows in table
        if (Number(response.headers.get('X-Pagination-Current-Page')) < 2) {
          this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;  // Set paginator on page = n ?
        }
        this.paginator.pageSize = Number(response.headers.get('X-Pagination-Per-Page'));  // Set Items per page
        this.paginator.length = Number(response.headers.get('X-Pagination-Total-Count')); // Set count all data
      });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    let queryParamMap = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap;
    if (queryParamMap.get('page')) {
      this.paginator.pageIndex = Number(queryParamMap.get('page'));
    }

    if (queryParamMap.get('pageSize')) {
      this.paginator.pageSize = Number(queryParamMap.get('per-page'));
    }

    this.fetchFromAPI();

    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
```

Comment: If your paginator is not under a *ngIf (it's always visible in the component) you can use `@ViewChild(MatPaginator,{static:true})` and you can check in ngOnInit.